# What is the most concise Clojure equivalent for Ruby's Dir.glob()?

Tags: ruby, clojure

What's the easiest way to do something like this in Clojure?

```
require 'csv'
Dir["data/*.csv"].each do |file|
  File.readlines(file).each do |line|
    x, y, z = *CSV.parse_line(line)
    # process this data
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the shortest I've seen:

```lisp
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(filter #(.endsWith (.getName %) ".csv") (file-seq (io/file dir))))
```

From https://github.com/brentonashworth/one/blob/master/src/lib/clj/one/reload.clj#L28

Comment: you forgot :as io in the require

Answer (score 6):

Probably not the most concise possible, but perhaps something like the following?

```lisp
(use 'clojure-csv.core)

(doseq [file (.listFiles (File. "data/"))]
  (if (.matches (.getName file) ".*[.]CSV$")
    (doseq [[x y z] (parse-csv (slurp file))]
       "... do whatever stuff you want with x, y, z..."))))
```

N.B. uses the [clojure-csv](https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-csv) library.

This would be more elegant and shorter if I could find an obvious way to get a filtered directory list without resorting to regexes.... but it eludes me for the moment

**UPDATE:**

Brian's link to [Java support for globbing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) is also useful and interesting and offers a more general/robust approach than simple regexes - however it depends on Java 1.7 (too cutting edge for some?) and it doesn't really shorten the code much.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html describes Java support for globbing.  Regex is probably easier.

Comment: hmmm I see - yes regex does seem simpler! looks like a good candidate for a handy wrapper function though.... do you think that would be welcome in clojure.contrib somewhere?

Comment: @mikera: Thank you, you just eliminated my desire to try Clojure. I'm staying with Ruby :)